# Post Facebook event via javascript SDK, not getting any response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create event via my website.I am not getting any response while post event.

### Below is my code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>


<span id='fbinfo'><fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name></span>



    <div id="fb-root"></div>


    <span id='fbinfo'><fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name></span>
    <!-- USE 'Asynchronous Loading' version, for IE8 to work
    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=path%>/js/socialNetwork.js"></script> -->
    <script>

    FB.init({appId: appid, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // var session = FB.getSession();
              fbtoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                fbuserid = response.authResponse.userID;;
            }
   // alert("fbtoken"+fbtoken);
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
       //  var session = FB.getSession();
           fbtoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          fbuserid = response.authResponse.userID;;
        }
        else{
            loginFB();
     }
     // alert("fbtoken 2"+fbtoken);
    });

    function loginFB() {
     FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
              // var session = FB.getSession();
               fbtoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
             fbuserid = response.authResponse.userID;;
            }
      }, {scope:’create_event'});
     // alert("fbtoken"+fbtoken);
    }

    function logoutFB() {
       FB.logout(function(response) {
         // user is now logged out
     });
    }

        function createEvent(name, startTime, endTime, location, description) {

            var eventData = {
                "access_token": fbtoken,
                "start_time" : startTime,
                 "end_time": endTime,
              "location" : location,
               "name" : name,
               "description": description,
               "privacy":"OPEN"
         };


          FB.api("/me/events","post",eventData,function(response){
            alert(response.error);
            if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert("Response "+response.id);
             } else {
                   alert("Post ID: " + response.id);
              }
         });
        }

        function createMyEvent(){
            var name = "My Amazing Event";
       var startTime = "10/29/2015 12:00 PM";
        var endTime = "10/29/2015 06:00 PM";
      var location = "Dhaka";
       var description = "It will be freaking awesome";
       createEvent(name, startTime,endTime, location, description);
       alert(name);
    }

</script>
```

I am getting the response.id as invalid.
So because of that i think event is not created on my FB wall..

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_games

Comment: But you can't. It is not possible

Comment: Ok thanks for the update..@WizKid..Is there any way that i can create event via code?

Comment: read my answer again. it´s not possible. again: you can´t create events via code. there is no way. create events directly on facebook.